# Log tables for scheduled jobs in dbt

Tags: google-bigquery, dbt

I am super new to dbt and wanted to see if there is a way to log the success/failure of scheduled dbt jobs in a table. I am currently using bigquery as my data warehouse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to `dbt`'s [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/events-logging), events are logged to `logs/dbt.log` file at your project folder, along with `stdout` at your terminal. As you're dealing with scheduled jobs, the file-based option would be more appropriate.

You can pass the `--debug` and the `--log-format json` arguments to your dbt jobs [for structured logging messages](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/global-configs#log-formatting), which would look like:

```
dbt --debug --log-format json run
```

Along with that, you could parse the success or failure of your jobs easily by looking, when available, at the `node_info` complex field and its `node_status` subfield. This will give you the results of your jobs when they eventually finish. The `node_name` subfield will give you the correspondent dbt model.

For more information, look at the [structured logging](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/events-logging#structured-logging) section of the documentation.  For a very detailed view of the jobs' metadata, look at this [`dbt`'s code block that generates it](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/HEAD/core/dbt/contracts/results.py#L61-L74).